# index doesn't run with innodb

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a problem when running the following script in mysql 5.0.92. I'm aware there's a problem with indexes, but can't figure it out. Any help very appreciated

```
CREATE TABLE Foundation (
MemberID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
MemberCategory VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
Invitation TINYINT(1) NULL,
Accepted TINYINT(1) NULL,
PersonID INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (MemberID),

INDEX (PersonID)
FOREIGN KEY (PersonID) REFERENCES Persons (PersonID)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION )


ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: Where is `Persons` table definition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a missing comma right after `INDEX (PersonID)`. The foreign key must have exactly the same definition in both tables.

So PersonId has to have the same definition in the Persons table:

`PersonID INT NOT NULL,`

Even miniscule changes like unsigned will get you the 150 errorno.